# Умножение полиномов

Tags: java

Есть парсер в ОПЗ, пишу функцию для преобразования полиномов из ОПЗ код такой

```
public void calculate() {

    Stack < String > buffer = new Stack < String > ();

    while (!stackRPN.empty()) {
        if (isNumber(stackRPN.peek())) {
            stackAnswer.push(stackRPN.pop());
        } else if (isVariable(stackRPN.peek())) {
            stackAnswer.push(stackRPN.pop());
        } else if (isOperator(stackRPN.peek())) {

            buffer.push(stackAnswer.pop());
            buffer.push(stackAnswer.pop());
            String ex = buffer.pop() + stackRPN.pop() + buffer.pop();
            stackAnswer.push(ex);
            buffer.clear();

        }
    }
```

Функция собирает из стека полиномы, помогите понять когда все полиномы собраны и можно их умножать?
stackRPN=[x, 5, -, 2, x, *, 3, ^, x, x, 2, ^, 9, -, *, +, *];
stackAnswer содержит такие строки:

1. [x-5]
2. [x-5, 2*x]
3. [x-5, 2*x^3]
4. [x-5, 2*x^3, x, x^2]
5. **[x-5, 2*x^3, x, x^2-9]** как поймать эту точку?
6. [x-5, 2*x^3, x*x^2-9]
7. [x-5, 2*x^3+x*x^2-9]
8. [x-5*2*x^3+x*x^2-9]

это парсер методом сортировочной станции

```
public void parse(String expression) throws ParseException {

    // cleaning stacks
    stackOperations.clear();
    stackRPN.clear();

    // make some preparations
    expression = expression.replace(" ", "").replace("(-", "(0-")
        .replace(",-", ",0-");
    if (expression.charAt(0) == '-') {
        expression = "0" + expression;
    }
    // splitting input string into tokens
    StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(expression,
    OPERATORS + "()", true);

    // loop for handling each token - shunting-yard algorithm
    while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String token = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
        if (isOpenBracket(token)) {
            stackOperations.push(token);
        } else if (isCloseBracket(token)) {
            while (!stackOperations.empty() && !isOpenBracket(stackOperations.lastElement())) {
                stackRPN.push(stackOperations.pop());
            }
            stackOperations.pop();
            if (!stackOperations.empty()) {
                stackRPN.push(stackOperations.pop());
            }
        } else if (isNumber(token) || isVariable(token)) {
            stackRPN.push(token);

        } else if (isOperator(token)) {
            while (!stackOperations.empty() && isOperator(stackOperations.lastElement()) && getPrecedence(token) <= getPrecedence(stackOperations.lastElement())) {
                stackRPN.push(stackOperations.pop());
            }
            stackOperations.push(token);
        }
    }
    while (!stackOperations.empty()) {
        stackRPN.push(stackOperations.pop());
    }

    // reverse stack

    System.out.println(stackRPN);
    Collections.reverse(stackRPN);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если вы работаете со строчными значениями этих переменных

1. из `stackRPN` находите последнее число [x, 5, -, 2, x, *, 3, ^, x, x, 2, ^, **9** (тут 13 символов)
2. считаете количество символов до этого числа
3. теперь при каждом шаге `stackAnswer` проверяете размер без запятых (,)

   ```
   [x-5, 2*x^3, x, x^2-9] => [x-52*x^3xx^2-9] // тут 14 символов
   ```

если количество символов `stackRPN` -1 =  количество символов `stackAnswer` значит вы нашли вашу строку

**2 вариант**

из `stackRPN` считаем количество операций

```
[x, 5, -, 2, x, *, 3, ^, x, x, 2, ^, 9, -, *, +, *] => [-, *,^, ^, -, *, +, *] // 8 шт
```

и вычесляем последные ТОЛЬКО операторы (без значений)

```
[x, 5, -, 2, x, *, 3, ^, x, x, 2, ^, 9, -, *, +, *] => [-, *, +, *] // 4 шт
```

значит **(8 - 4) + 1 = 5** шаг это и есть полный вариант полиномов

может так ?

Comment: это будет работать если в конце ОПЗ нет переменной или числа т.е. в выражении типо такого (x-5)(2x^3+x(x-9))x не сработает

Comment: тогда этот де метод, только наоборот, с правой стороны считаем сколько операций. обновил ответ P.S. просто как работает ОПЗ  не помню

Comment: она переводит из инфиксной в постфиксную (1+3)*4 --> 1 3 + 4 * операнд действует на последние два числа в стеке. Как то так